# How to list S3 bucket Delimiter paths

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, delimiter

**How to list S3 bucket Delimiter paths?**

Basically I want to list all of the "directories" and or "sub-directories" in a s3 bucket. I know these don't physically exist. Basically I want all the objects that contain the delimiter and then only return the key path before for the delimiter. Starting under a prefix would be even better but at the bucket level should be enough.

Example S3 Bucket:

```
root.json
/2018/cats/fluffy.png
/2018/cats/gary.png
/2018/dogs/rover.png
/2018/dogs/jax.png
```

I would like to then do something like:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.list_objects(only_show_delimiter_paths=True)
```

Result

```
/2018/
/2018/cats/
/2018/dogs/
```

I don't see any way to do this natively using: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects

I could pull all the object names and do this in my application code but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon S3 page in boto3 has [this example](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#list-top-level-common-prefixes-in-amazon-s3-bucket):

> **List top-level common prefixes in Amazon S3 bucket**
>
> This example shows how to list all of the top-level common prefixes in an Amazon S3 bucket:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
result = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket', Delimiter='/')
for prefix in result.search('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(prefix.get('Prefix'))
```

But, it only shows top-level prefixes.

So, here's some code to print all the 'folders':

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
objects = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

keys = [o['Key'] for o in objects['Contents']]

folders = {k[:k.rfind('/')+1] for k in keys if k.rfind('/') != -1}

print ('\n'.join(folders))
```

Comment: I was looking for simple way to get top level keys; this works perfectly for me. but want to confirm this will work ok if I have more than 1000 records... Also is there a way that I can print the prefix without / for example top level prints  inbound/ outbound/ test/ .... but I want to  print them as a list [inbound, outbound, test]

Comment: @Moe Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.